# why define lt when operator< exists?

Tags: c++, vector, operators, class-template

A piece of code for vector operations contains these class template definitions:

```
template <class T>
class lt { 
    public: 
    static int compare(T a, T b) { return(a < b); } 
};
template <class T>
class gt { 
    public: 
    static int compare(T a, T b) { return(a > b); } 
};
```

But why? It's not using extra exception handling, and it relies on objects of class `T` already having `operator<` and `operator>`. Is it not just as easy/easier to use the operators? Or should one use template classes for comparisons?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code this is used in, hard to say, but I expect it's used so that you can select "sort ascending" and "sort descending", respectively.

Comment: Without knowing the full piece of code, and the design decisions behind it, there is really no way of answering this without guessing or having psychic abilities.

Comment: There's also the question of why `compare` returns an `int`, rather than a `bool`.  In the standard library, the `compare` functions return `int`, but with a value less than, equal to or greater than zero, according to whether the first argument is less than, equal to or greater than the second.

Comment: The file containing the definitions is here [ https://sites.google.com/site/jivsoft/Home/compute-ranks-of-elements-in-a-c---array-or-vector/ranker.h ] -sorting and ranking of numerical vectors. The ascending/descending point makes sense (the comparison function can now be passed as a pointer) but could also have been implemented with operators without loss of genericity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those templates can be used whenever someone expects a binary predicate, i.e. a free function taking two parameters. An overloaded `operator<` may not be defined as a free, binary function, so these templates serve as a sort of adapter to let you use existing operators no matter how they were defined, as long as the *expression* `a < b` can be resolved.

Note that the standard already provides very similar* templates; they're called `std::less` and `std::greater`, and they're used for example by the ordered, associative containers.

<sub>*) The standard library predicates provide additional guarantees on how they work on pointers.</sub>

Comment: Predicates must have overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens in std::less [ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less ]! Excellent, thanks!

Comment: @VasilyBiryukov: In the OP's case, you'd use `&gt<T>::compare` as the predicate, not `gt<T>()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Thing is that comparison is not always numerical.Sometimes two objects can be compared and **greater than** or **less Than** can have new definitions .For example in a **class** that holds objects of type **Coordinates** Comparison can be defined in a custom way.
For example :

```
Coordinate c1(3,5)
Coordinate c2(4,2)
```

We can overload the `> operator` to return True for `c1>c2` whenever `c1.x > c2.x` or `c1.y>c2.y`

Comment: That explains why you may need to define / overload `operator>` but not what the use of extra class templates would be.

Comment: @alle_meije The template is a generic way of defining the Class which you intend to run a comparison on. In this Case `Coordinate` is just an example for that. `<T>` represents an arbitrary class.